# I have multiple queues and i want to set priorities to these queues. Is it possible in JMS?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, priority-queue

If I have the 3 queues of priority 1,2 & 3 respectively. I want my consumer to consume first from queue withe priority 1, then 2 & so on. If in case queue with higher priority is empty, the consumer can consume from the queue with lower priority.
Is it possible to achieve from JMS or ActiveMQ or any other way?How?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to control that logic yourself using this method.  To ActiveMQ, or any other JMS provider, you are just using another queue.

However, you can use a single queue for message priority.  There are a couple different ways on how to do this as described [in the documentation.](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html)

If you want your consumer to be as simple as possible then have the broker figure out the priority.  Otherwise you'll need to mess with multiple consumers or inefficient single consumer logic with selectors to consume.

In both cases, your producer will just need to be smart enough to set the JMSPriority header to whatever priority the logic says it should be.

The only downside really is the fact that you have a broker side config to set up for that queue specifically rather than everything being automatic.

Comment: Can you explain how will the "broker figure out the priority"? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: If you configure a queue polciy with the prioritizedMessages="true" then the broker will dispatch messages in order of priority rather than FIFO.  The priorities ActiveMQ uses are somewhat dependent on the persistent store you are using.  All is explained in the link I gave you.

Comment: We are using SOAP over JMS. If suppose we are giving 10 requests & these request messages persists in queue, these requests are processed only one at a time. How can we processes more than one requests in parallel?

Comment: Have more consumers (independent or concurrent). You will only ever be given one message per consumer at a time. No matter if you have 1 or 15 queues, you can't really get around that.